# Bash not starting in shell properly

Tags: bash

When I open my terminal (OS X 10.10.3) I can't run some commands including the commands that are in my ~/.bashrc, but then if I launch bash from that terminal, all those commands work, as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first open the terminal, bash runs `.bash_profile`.  You probably have modified `.bashrc` to add node to your `PATH`, but that is not executed until you run bash within the terminal.

This difference leads to people advising to do this in `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -r ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

and on other systems, packagers do this for you as part of your user-directory skeleton, either in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (generally under `/etc/skel`).

(see *[What's the difference between .bashrc, .bash_profile, and .environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)*, which goes into more detail).